# Control Javascript/CSS elements with Python via Websocket?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, websocket

I'm trying to control the Font Size property via the below python code. I've sent the data via Websocket and Python and JS seem to work perfectly. I'm now just trying to use that data to control the font size JS/CSS property but, I've no luck. Below are my code attempts. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance! : )

```js
function WebSocketTest() {

            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8768/echo");

               ws.onopen = function() {

                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };

               ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  document.querySelector("h1").style.fontSize = evt.data;



               };

               ws.onclose = function() {

                  // websocket is closed.

               };
            } else {

               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
```

```css
/*! Generated by Font Squirrel (https://www.fontsquirrel.com) on June 3, 2020 */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'spartanthin';
    src: url('fonts/SpartanUnconv/Spartan-VariableFont_wght.ttf');
    font-weight: 100 900;
    font-style: normal;


}




h1 {

margin-bottom: 10px;
font-family: 'spartanthin';
font-weight: var(--font-weight);
font-size: 15px;
text-align: left;
position: relative;


}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<p>A Black Fox Jumped Over A Fence</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
import asyncio
    import websockets

    async def echo(websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
            await websocket.send(str(900)) #FontSize Value

    start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8778)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

that `async for message in websocket:` means your server only responds to messages from client and your client does not send any messages.

try it like so

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo(websocket, path):
    await websocket.send(str(900)) #FontSize Value

start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8778)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

also, change the JS part `WebSocket("ws://localhost:8768/echo");` to `WebSocket("ws://localhost:8778");` (so it corresponds with your server).
And I'am not sure if you are calling that js function, so if u dont have `WebSocketTest();` anywhere, place it to script tag in html or directly to a js file after that `WebSocketTest` function definition.